# Really Long Breath intake while meditation

Tags: meditation

Hi I am so called Brahman Hindu(although i am an atheist) but i have been meditating since the last 2 weeks and i want to say it is hands down one of the most beautiful experience ever.Although lately i have been going deeper as people like to call it and want to share my experience regarding this deep state and also need some guidance if any one can help me.

So this happened yesterday while my meditation (i do it by concentrating my breath) i guess i was so deep that my breath felt like really long i got scared and snapped out of it.Today while doing it again i counted the seconds i can intake air through nose which was around 10 seconds which is weird i guess and long considering my past xD(calculated using the sound of the second's hand of wall clock). I am curious as to how should i go deeper by the same breathing concentration exercise or should i stop breathing kind of a thing after i reach this state(cause i can hold my breath also for a long time).Also what is next for me from here on.

Thanks for the help/guidance and sorry for wasting your time.
TL;DR:- deep state i feel like taking real long breath intake which is scaring me should i go deeper or like do something else also how to proceed forward

Comment: 1. You cannot be a Hindu and an atheist. You may say you were born into a bramhan family but that is irrelevant to your Q  2. Sorry but this is not the right forum for you to seek advice on this particular aspect. Do not try to stop breathing or do any breath feats without the guidance of a proper guru. If you want to go deeper, try observing (or noting as it is called in buddhism). Good journey.

Comment: @moonstar2001 yes i agree with your point 1 obviously and thats the best way to put it also yes it was irrelevant but i thought that most of the people doing this are doing to meet god or stuff( i have certain other reasons for doing it) and mentioned it because of that.

Comment: Regarding Q.2 what are the best forums for this thing. Also as i believe i have come this far on my own instincts without any proper guru but i am starting to push myself to weird territories and need some guidance in that matter. Also i am not going to choke myself obviously by not breathing lol.

Comment: Close. Personal advice not allowed on this forum. Find your guru!

Comment: OK wow. Quick Question how to find a guru who is the most knowledgeable and that also for free(will this be also considered as a personal advise) and also if this forum is not for advise and sharing of knowledge than what is the purpose of hinduism.stackexchange. I believe in this advent of technology and internet everyone deserves a chance to get knowledge and the more you try to keep yourself reserved and keep power and knowledge in hands of selected few the more closer will you be towards extinction.

Comment: Learn from websites like coursera etc.. who are giving chance to every kid in every country/every part of world to become an astrophysicist or whatever he wants to be. Knowledge should be free guidance should be free.Also won't the guru be giving advises only and how to know if those advises are True and not False.Anyways these comments are going in the philosophical era. So i will shy away from going to that side but still thanks for any kind of help

Comment: @Sanchit frame the question in such way that it looks like a question and not personal advice

Comment: You don't need to find a guru just to learn breathing which is natural. Either do PrAnAyAm according to the answer or just watch your breath. Be aware or your inhale & exhale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deep and rhythmic breathing is part of [ujjayi prAnAyAma](https://www.ashtangayoga.info/ashtangayoga/practice/980101-breathing-ujjayi/#). You should not get scared of it.

The more deep and long you inhale it makes you more oxygenated. After a prolonged session your breathing frequency drops. This is also natural because your body has enough oxygen and hence it breathes less as the need is minimal.

Also this state will give rise to inner peace and tranquility and thoughtlessness.

But make sure that breathing is abdominal.

Comment: Right. One don't need to find a guru just to learn breathing, which is natural. I like this suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Being a Brahmin, you have accumulated some good deeds from past lives which can make you successful in spirituality or Brahman jnAna in no time. What you achieved is a form of DhArana, if you don't wanna waste your Brahminhood you can continue your meditation while being aware or concentrated on **the GAP** which you experienced, you will open the door of inner taste.  From the commentary of [24th verse Vijnanabhairava tantra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/dv%C4%81dash%C4%81nta-in-which-direction-from-the-tip-of-the-nose) -

> There are two points or poles between which respiration goes
>   on constantly. One of these is dvadaSAnta in the outer space
>   where prAna or exhalation ends and the other hrt or the centre
>   inside the body where apAna or inhalation ends. At each of these
>   points, there is visrAnti or **rest for a split second**. **The breath
>   does not actually stop there totally but remains in the form of
>   a throb of sakti in suspended animation and then again the
>   breathing process starts. One should contemplate over the sakti
>   that appears in the period of rest and should remain mindful
>   of it even while the breathing process starts. By constant practice
>   of this dhArana, he will realize the state of plenitude of Bhairava**.

Comment: Brahman jnAna in no time--- Is it that easy?

Comment: @Rickross Not easy, but for many journey is not fresh, already trodden in past lives. I answered for him as he was closer to the gap in no time.

Comment: That one is born in a Brahmin family does not in any way prove that he is already spiritually quite advanced by virtue of its past life sadhanas. If it was that the case then why he is an atheist to start with? Does it indicate great spiritual merit coming forward from past lives?

Comment: Yes @Rickross ,